# ClassNotFoundException while using Class.forName()

Tags: java

I am trying to use Java reflection to read class files and output its contents. Here is my Reflect.java file code that throws the error:

```
String className = classNames.get(classNum).replace(".class", "");
        String packageAndClassName = packageName + "." + className;
        System.out.println(packageAndClassName);
        try{
            Class<?> c = Class.forName(packageAndClassName);
```

My command to read a package's contents looks like this

```
java -classpath . reflect.Reflect package /u/username/Desktop/Experiment/others/package/
```

Here, arg[0]= package and arg[1]=/u/username/Desktop/Experiment/others/package/

My classpath looks like so:

```
/u/username/Desktop/Experiment/reflect/:/u/username/Desktop/Experiment/others/package/
```

"others" contains the package. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I have looked up a lot of answers and they involve typing in the whole name of the Reflect class, which I am doing in my command. Any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Comment: How do you set `packageName` in your code?

Comment: Nvm, I get the packageName from the args passed to main(). so args[0] is the packageName and args[1] is the absolute path to the packageName

Comment: Have you replaced the slashes '/' with periods? A java package is in the form of `com.example.package` So if `others` is your src folder, it would be `others.package.YourClass`

Comment: Tgsith61591, I did that, but it gave me a  nullpointer exception. I don't think that is even the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to the classpath parameter. I'm guessing the class you are trying to load is not in the path so you need to add the package directory there.

The other option is to use the [UrlClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html)

Comment: I modified my terminal command, so it looks as such:

java -cp /u/username/Desktop/Experiment/  reflect.Reflect  packageName  /u/username/Desktop/Experiment/others/packageName/

I am still running into the Classnotfound exception

Comment: Can you show the output when you print "packageAndClassName"

Comment: Nvm guys, I got it to work, though I had to write a bash file to make it work as opposed to having a terminal command work